# trying to send email from database value

Tags: c#, linq, mailmessage

I have a method returning an email address as a string to a chunk of code that sends an email, but I'm getting the error: "The specified string is not in the form required for an e-mail address."

Here's the method that returns the email address:

```
public static string getSignerByID(int signerID)
{
    using (dbPSREntities10 myEntities = new dbPSREntities10())
    {
        var thisId = myEntities.refAuthSigners.Where(x => x.refAuthSignerID == signerID).Select(x => x.NetworkEmail).ToList();

        var formattedValue = thisId.ToString();

        return formattedValue;

    }
}
```

Here's the code that sends the email:

```
//method to send approved email
    public static void sendApprovedEmail(string contactFirstName, string contactLastName, string contactEmail, int signer)
    {
        //Email one
        string fileName = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/ApprovedEmail.txt");
        string mailBody = File.ReadAllText(fileName);

        mailBody = mailBody.Replace("##ContactFirstName##", contactFirstName);
        mailBody = mailBody.Replace("##ContactLastName##", contactLastName);

        MailMessage myMessage = new MailMessage();
        myMessage.Subject = "PSR has been approved";
        myMessage.Body = mailBody;

        string signerEmailAddress = getSignerByID(signer);

        myMessage.From = new MailAddress("no-reply@test.com", "no-reply@test.com");
        myMessage.To.Add(new MailAddress(contactEmail));
        myMessage.To.Add(new MailAddress(signerEmailAddress));// this is the email address from the database that errors out.

        SmtpClient mySmtpClient = new SmtpClient();
        mySmtpClient.Send(myMessage);
    }
```

any idea why the variable "signerEmailAddress" wouldn't work? The value int he database is a varchar(50) and is definitely a valid email address. Thanks!

Comment: The returned value from `getSignerById` isn't a valid email address. Probably something to do with the fact that it is retrieved using `List.ToString()`, which makes no sense. Learn to debug and inspect the value. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/79508/Mastering-Debugging-in-Visual-Studio-2010-A-Beginn

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`thisId` will relturn **list** of network emails:

```
var thisId = myEntities.refAuthSigners
                       .Where(x => x.refAuthSignerID == signerID)
                       .Select(x => x.NetworkEmail)
                       .ToList();
```

Calling `ToString()` will return you list's type name. Something like:

```
"System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Namespace.NetworkEmail]"
```

Which definitely not looks like email address. Possibly you want to use `FirstOrDefault()` instead of `ToList()`. That will return you network address of first signer with provided id. You should check whether returned value is not null, and then call `ToString()` (if you have `ToString()` overridden on network email type).